# Convert tradingview heiken ashi with ema to Mql5

Tags: tradingview-api, handle, moving-average, indicator, mql5

I try to add heiken Ashi price close handle in IMA.
But i don't know how to do.
For example like this :

```
ha = heikinashi(tickerid)
ha_close = security(ha, res, close[1])
ma = ema(ha_close[1], 30)
```

Thank you all.

I try to convert a tradingview code to mql5